# ListView renders empty rows in React Native 0.39.2

Tags: listview, react-native

I updated my RN implementation to 0.39.2 and get this weird behaviour in the ListView Component. See image below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<ListView style={{marginBottom: 50, paddingTop: 10}}
  onTouchMove={(e)=>{
    _listViewDirtyPressEnabled = false;
  }}
  onTouchEnd={(e)=>{
    _listViewDirtyPressEnabled = true;
  }}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
    />
  }
  pageSize={5}
  onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
  dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.calls)}
  renderRow={this.renderCallRows}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  scrollRenderAheadDistance={400}
  onEndReachedThreshold={100}
  initialListSize={10}
  renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) =>
    <View
      key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`}
      style={[styles.separator, {marginLeft: width * 0.05}]}
    />
  }
/>
```

Happens when I add new rows to the list by using `concat`. This didn't happen on RN 0.24.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the solution. This is actually a styling issue and not a RN Api issue.

Ended up removing `flex: 1` from the each cell component.